# modify a spacial format date pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I am new using pandas and i have this dataframe

```
| colDat      |
| 09 Mar 2021 |
| 09 Feb 2021 |
```

I want to add a new column to convert the format date :

```
| colDat      | newColDat |
| 09 Mar 2021 | 2021-03-09T00:00:00.0000|
| 09 Feb 2021 | 2021-02-09T00:00:00.0000|
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

To convert your date to ISO format, assuming the initial column is text:

```py
df['newColDat'] = df.colDat.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).isoformat()+'.0000')
```

Result:

```
    colDat      newColDat
0   09 Mar 2021 2021-03-09T00:00:00.0000
1   09 Feb 2021 2021-02-09T00:00:00.0000
```

Comment: Thanks Anurag! That's more accurate.

Comment: THANK YOU ANURAG, exactly what i needed